# Secure Admin registration with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I feel like the answer is "it's build in, dummy" but I can't find the documentation to verify my suspicions.

I'm using Devise for a Rails app and my question, in short, is: "how do I create new admin users?" The reason I ask is that following the Devise documentation seems to just create a structure that would expose the /admins/sign_up URL, similar to how it exposes the /users/sign_up URL for new users.

Now, *generally*, I wouldn't expect anyone to go to /admins/sign_up just to see if they could. But I don't really want to bank on that, and create a (pretty gaping) vulnerability. So, my follow up question is: "how do I secure the admin signup so that only the right people see it?" and/or "what is a better alternative to handle admin accounts with devise?"

**EDIT 1**
I found discovered ([in their docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role)) the obvious answer to securing the admin sign up. If I remove `:registerable` and a couple other configuration options in the admin model, and run the migration with the appropriate settings, the route simply isn't available to reach any kind of admin signup. Great.
I guess my first question now still stands: "how do I now create a new admin?" It's not like just anyone can go in and register to be an admin now, but I also don't see how I or anyone else could create an admin account.

Comment: Just open up a rails console and create your admin user.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That is appropriate? I had thought of that, but it seems to be a vulnerability others might be able to exploit as well?

Comment: How will others get access to your rails console?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Haha, that's an obvious/fair point - to be honest I'm newish at this, and I'm just being overly cautious. I hope. Again, this was my thought too, I'm simply worried about security, which I know little enough about to begin with. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just don't tell anyone your heroku credentials and you should be fine :)

Comment: That is easy enough. Thanks @SergioTulentsev!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise is great gem for authentication but It lacks some of the key features like you wanted only admin to create users. It's pretty much general purpose requirement for lot of projects.

There is not a single line solution in devise for this problem.

Here are few things which devise does/suppose.

1. Signup is public
2. Already login user cannot sign up
3. Newly signed up user is auto logged in after successful signup.

Now we are going to change all of the above three behaviour

I am assuming your model for users is `user` and configuring devise for `user`

First of all you need to override devise registration controller.

```
 ## app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :redirect_unless_admin,  only: [:new, :create]
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication

  private
  def redirect_unless_admin
    unless current_user.try(:admin?)
      flash[:error] = "Only admins can do that"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    true
  end
end


# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations'}
end
```

Here is how all of the above three issues are handled.

1. The `before_action` ensures that a user is logged in, and   redirects them unless they are admin, if they try to sign up.
2. The already logged in issue is caused by Devise's `require_no_authentication` method and skipping it resolves the issue.
3. Next is that the newly created user is automatically signed in. The `sign_up` helper method which does this is overridden to do prevent automatic signin.

Comment: I follow about 98% of what you're saying, and it makes sense. I think that it doesn't quite address my issue...I'm trying to make admin users, not have admins create other users.

That said, I can't promise that I will not use some of the clever things you pointed out. Thank you!

Comment: You only need one time admin user or Admin user can create other admin users?

Comment: AH...now I see where you're going with this. I think the last 2% of what I was missing just clicked in my brain. Thanks for filling in the gap! Of course once I set an admin user per Sergio's suggestion above, I can implement your code to allow that admin to create other admins (which will certainly be a future requirement). Perfect!

Comment: yeah that's the way. You can write a migration or add a default user in seed file. Then login with that user and create other users with the above code

Comment: Perfect! I've got my initial admin users set up, so now all I need to do is implement what you have here and I'll be able to add additional admins via a form going forward, if and only if the logged in user is admin :) Thanks again!

Comment: Haha, I will certainly accept it when I've tested it out...I've no doubt it's the right way to go about it, and correct code, but still have the implementing to do. Not to worry, my friend as soon as I get your code working in my app you get all the credit :)